# Android program quits trying to display a jpg image

Tags: android

Here is my program.

```
public class MathsExplorer extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private GraphicsView view;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(view);

    }
}
public class GraphicsView extends View {

    public GraphicsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        String background = "/Maths Explorer/bin/res/drawable/MC900436279.jpg";
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(background);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, 10, 10, null);
    }
}
```

It quits right away with the error "Unfortunatly, Maths Explorer has stopped."

Can anyone help me? I'm not sure, I'm just trying to display an image.

Comment: are sure you need to refer the image from bin **"/Maths Explorer/bin/res/drawable/MC900436279.jpg"** .. i guess it is **res/drawable**

Answer (score 0):

I think that path to file is wrong, you can't do that.
Try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource%28android.content.res.Resources,%20int%29).